# material ui installation can you find me a solution here

Tags: npm

```
added 30 packages, removed 8 packages, changed 1 package, and audited 1549 packages in 27s

244 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

already tried the version change